# How to print the missing elements using JMeter?

Tags: json, groovy, jmeter, performance-testing, web-api-testing

I have 2 get api's which returns the response code consisting of id number and title.

sample responses of API_1 is:(with 100 id's)

```
{

   "result": "OK",

   "obj" : {

                "list" : [
                  {
                     "id" : 924946341,
                     "title" : "qweryuy"
                   },
                    {
                     "id" : 8361,
                     "title" : "kgsklp"
                   }
                ]
          }
}
```

API-2 also has similar response like this.

I want to compare both the api's id number and want to print the missing elements.

So I have used json extractor and extracted the id of 2 api's. API-1 has the extracted variable name as Id.

And API-2 has extracted variable name as c_Id.

In json extractor for 1st API i have extracted something like this:

variable name :id

json path: $..id

match no :-1

checked the suffix ALL box

similarly for api2 also I have used the same with varivable name as c_id

I have used beanshell assertion to compare if they are same, but couldn't get how to show the missing values, so I got suggestion to use JSR223 Assertion, I have used the code given, The code is:

```
log.info('id1: '+vars.get('id_ALL'))

log.info('id2: '+vars.get('c_id_ALL'))

def id1 = org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.substringBetween(vars.get('id_ALL'), '{', '}').split(',').collect()

def id2 = org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.substringBetween(vars.get('c_id_ALL'), '{', '}').split(',').collect()

def missing = org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils.disjunction(id1, id2)

log.info('Missing values: ' +missing)
```

When I run the script in view result tree I am getting an assertion failure message:

> javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: org for class: Script10

When I see in the Log viwer panel I can see

id:924946341,8361

c_id: 924946341,09272,8361

and then instead of missing values I am getting this error:

> ERROR o.a.j.a.JSR223Assertion: Problem in JSR223 script: JSR223 Assertion javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: org for class: Script10 at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:320) ~[groovy-jsr223-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7] at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyCompiledScript.eval(GroovyCompiledScript.java:71) ~[groovy-jsr223-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7] at javax.script.CompiledScript.eval(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_321] at org.apache.jmeter.util.JSR223TestElement.processFileOrScript(JSR223TestElement.java:217) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.3] at org.apache.jmeter.assertions.JSR223Assertion.getResult(JSR223Assertion.java:50) [ApacheJMeter_components.jar:5.4.3] at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processAssertion(JMeterThread.java:931) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.3]

I tried using beanshell assertion to see if the id and c_id values are picking up or not, the extracted variable values are picked up fine.

Is there something I am doing wrong? or can you suggest any other way achieving displaying of such missing elements in JMeter? I can't check 100's of id's manually when they are in jumbled form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I cannot reproduce your issue, maybe it's something environmental depending on your Java version and the libraries you have in [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath).
2. Looking into your variables values it doesn't make sense to remove `{` and `}` characters as they're not there.
3. You can try using [`import` statement](https://groovy-lang.org/structure.html#_simple_import) instead of specifying fully qualified class names, i.e. change "your" code to something like:

   ```
   import org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils

   log.info('id1: '+vars.get('id_ALL'))

   log.info('id2: '+vars.get('c_id_ALL'))

   def id1 = vars.get('id_ALL').split(',').collect()

   def id2 =vars.get('c_id_ALL').split(',').collect()

   def missing = CollectionUtils.disjunction(id1, id2)

   log.info('Missing values: ' +missing)
   ```

Demo:

[image]

More information: [Scripting JMeter Assertions in Groovy - A Tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial)

Comment: Thank you this works, one more query if I  want to display the missing terms in view result tree how could it be done as it's not shown there, because the missing terms are only displayed in log viewer panel only